# SSRS 2008 R2 Last Record in Data Driven Subscription Takes Forever

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am running SSRS 2008 R2 and have a data driven subscription on a report. There are 44 rows returned in the data driven query so 44 reports will get posted to a SharePoint document library.

When I kick off the subscription, 43 of the reports are delivered in 3 minutes. The last one takes 20 minutes. There is nothing special about the parameters on the last one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out. Found the column ReportServer.dbo.Notifications.ProcessAfter. This was causing the "issue" which is probably not really an issue. Not sure why the report server code set this field so far into the future, but after some tweaking of my report parameters, this issue went away.

Comment: can you help witht his please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917941/how-to-exclude-column-from-a-report