# SSRS Remove Column from Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i am including column `13` as a dummy column here:

```
+----+---+---+---+----+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+
|    | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4  | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
+----+---+---+---+----+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+
|  1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |
|  2 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |
|  3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |
|  4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |
|  5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |
|  6 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |
|  7 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |
|  8 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |
|  9 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |
| 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |
+----+---+---+---+----+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+
```

the reason i am including a dummy column is so that IF columns `1` through `12` are all zero, i would still like to include an entry for that row.

as you can see row `1` would not have been included.

this report is generated by SSRS.

i am wondering if there is a way to HIDE column `13`?

is there some kind of conditional formatting i can do?

to clarify here's my query:

```
select tat.*, tat.tat as tat2 from tat
```

it is organized in the report this way:

[image]

this data set `[TAT]` contains dummy data specifically for column `13`

Comment: _"as you can see row 1 would not have been included."_ No, i cannot see the sql that omits that record.

Comment: I think OP is describing the matrix results in SSRS, not the output of a query. Артём Царионов: are you using a matrix or a table in SSRS? (That is, do you have column groups?)

Comment: @TimSchmelter i've explained further

Comment: @JamieF thank you very much for helping - yes i am using a matrix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specific columns in a column group can be hidden based on values with the following steps.

Right-click header of the column group you want to hide, `Column Group` -> `Group Properties`

[image: SSRS Column Group Properties]

Click on the `Visibility` pane and select `Show or hide based on an expression` radio button. Use an expression to determine when column is hidden.

`True` hides the column, `False` displays it. You will need to update the field name in my example to match your `month` field name.

[image: SSRS Column Group Visibility]

Answer (score 1):

Don't include column 13 in your select? If you are doing a `select *`, change it to `Select col1, col2, ...., col12`

Comment: thanks so much. i've explained furhter please review once more